# How to paste an open PopupMenu into answer?

Tags: discussion, support

I have been using SE Tools to paste graphics into answers.

I would like to paste an open `PopupMenu` into an answer.

However I can't seem to do it using SE Uploader.

I see it in other people's answers.

I am looking for the instructions on how to paste an open `PopupMenu` into an answer.

I am on Windows 7 on a PC.

Comment: The Windows built-in **Snipping Tool** has a delay setting that can be utilized for this purpose, as described in the [answer by m_goldberg](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1681/18476).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious answer would seem to be that, when this situation occurs, you should switch from SE tools to a screen grabber with more capability -- in particular, one with the capability to make delayed screen grabs. I can't make a specific recommendation because these things are OS specific and you do not mention what OS you run on.

Answer (score 0):

Without a third party utility, the only way seems to be the "Problem Steps Recorder".

You can find more info here:

https://superuser.com/questions/64182/can-windows-7-or-vistas-snipping-tool-capture-a-screen-10-seconds-later-and-ca